# Create map (Key,Value) structure in AngularJS and fill with data from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary

I have a list in AngularJS, $scope.list[];

What I want to know is how can I fill that list to fit a key,value structure  like this:

```
$scope.list[{key,value},{key,value}];
```

and I want to fill that "map" with data coming in json format:

```
 {
  exportData {
    id: 1,
    name : "Peter",
    lastname : "Smith"
    age : 36
  }
}
```

Where the **Id** is going to be the KEY and the rest of the strucure is going to be de VALUE

For example in a structure like this:

```
[
      1: {
        name : "Peter",
        lastname : "Smith"
        age : 36
      },
    2: {
        name : "John",
        lastname : "Carlos"
        age : 40
      },
    ]
```

Comment: I still don't get what you currently have, what the problem is, and what's your expected result..

Comment: but export data shouldn't be an array?

Comment: Hi @choz

What I have is just the reponse in JSON, and I was looking for something similar to a "map" in JS and AngularJS, my problem is that I dont know if there's something similar to a map in JS like for example in Java where you can declare a map object and then how can I fill that map with the values coming in my reponse, in this case is json format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I written the below code as per your need, hope it will help you:

```
var data = [
                  {
                    id: 1,
                    name : "Peter",
                    lastname : "Smith",
                    age : 36
                  }, {
                    id: 2,
                    name : "Peter",
                    lastname : "Smith",
                    age : 36
                  }
                ];

                $scope.itemList = [];
                angular.forEach(data, function(item){
                    var obj = {};
                    var valObj = {};

                    valObj.name = item.name;
                    valObj.lastname = item.lastname;
                    valObj.age = item.age;

                    obj[item.id] = valObj;
                    $scope.itemList.push(obj);
                });
```

Comment: Thank's for your time!

Comment: Hi Sunnet, one more question, according to this script how can I avoid pushing the value if the id already exists?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this function will help you

`$scope.transform = function(exportData){
    var _value = {};
    _value.name = exportData.name;
    _value.lastname = exportData.lastname;
    _value.age = exportData.age;
    var item = [exportData.id, _value];
    $scope.list.push(item);
}`

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'll try this =)